# Crunchbang asks for URIs to get build dependencies for php5

Tags: debian, php5

I'm trying to install PHP5, by compiling it myself.

I'm doing this on Crunchbang Linux, version 11. Specifically, the version using the 3.2 kernel. Crunchbang 11 is based on Debian. This is a 64-bit Virtual machine, running on a 64-bit Win7 Professional. Using Virtualbox 4.2

[This is my `sources.list` file](http://pastebin.com/rQJNwX7c)

```
## CRUNCHBANG
## Compatible with Debian Squeeze, but use at your own risk.
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main
#deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main

## CRUNCHBANG MULTIMEDIA
## Debian Multimedia Mirror
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/statler-mm squeeze main non-free
#deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/statler-mm squeeze main non-free

## CRUNCHBANG MOZILLA
## Debian Mozilla Mirror
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/statler-mozilla squeeze-backports iceweasel-release
#deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/statler-mozilla squeeze-backports iceweasel-release

## DEBIAN
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN SECURITY
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

## DEBIAN BACKPORTS
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

When I try to do `sudo apt-get build-dep php5`, I get the following output:

> Reading package lists...
>   Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

I'm not sure what's going on here. Can anyone point out what's missing in my setup?
Also, since I'm under 300 reputation on ServerFault, I can't add the "crunchbang" tag.

Comment: Your question is off topic for serverfault as it doesn't appear to relates to servers, networking or desktop infrastructure support in a professional capacity. It may be on topic for http://unix.stackexchange.com but please [search](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search) to see if there are questions that have answers that may help you first.

Comment: @HopelessN00b It's the default crunchbang sources.list. I didn't make it. The rest of the setup is just fine. It's a virtual machine meant for running php on linux. Criticizing that makes you come off as a condescending unix hipster.

Comment: @Iain I'm trying to compile PHP, with the obvious goal of running webpages off this VM. PHP is serverside application. So how is that **not** server-related? Oh and I just read the faq. Since when is serverfault limited to things in a professional capacity? Wasn't like that when it started. This means serverfault has basically declared itself to be of a higher class than all the other stackexchange sites. what a nice concept >_>

Comment: Context is important to us http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3714/why-is-my-question-being-voted-down-deleted

Comment: Not a higher class, just a different class. And anyway, that discussion belongs on meta, where it's been hashed out thousands of times already...

Answer (score 1):

You commented out all the source repositories in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Uncomment them.